# MVC c#.net Where is email html body in ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionmailer

We are using .html.cshtml  email template that generates email body into EmailResult object:

```
public EmailResult GetEmail()
{
    . . .
    return Email(emailTemplate, model);  
    // this goes first to emailTemplate.html.cshtml
    // inside emailTemplate.html.cshtml last statement is 
    // <div>
    //    @if (emailContent != "")
    //    {
    //       <text>@Html.Raw(emailContent)</text>
    //    }
    //
    //  Then it goes to _email_layout.cshtml
    //  where there is: @RenderBody() 
    //
    // only Then it returns as EmailResult
    // So, it seems EmailResult Should have email body somewhere ??

}
```

Then we need to extract created email text to assign to another variable:

```
EmailResult emr = GetEmail();
. . .
var htmlContent = emr.Mail.Body; // Body is null here, why ???
```

Where is email html body in the ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult ?
 Many thanks

Comment: EmailResult  namespace?

Comment: It's ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult, I've updated question

Comment: I don't think the body has been specified yet. It's not until the result is rendered that a view is selected and used to generate the body. It's sort of like when you return any other `ViewResult`. Here's the [source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8441214/) for `EmailResult`.

Comment: Thank you Scott,EmailResult source code confirmed what I found out during debugging. It seems Email body as text is saved in .Mail.AlternateViews.  I guess I will have to use .Mail.AlternateViews to get email text. Thank you